# Proof of an algebraic statement

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space. Let's also say that we have two linear operators: $A,B\in L(V)$ and $AB=0$. Then how do I prove that the sum of the ranks of operators is smaller than $n$, i.e. $r(A)+r(B)\leq n$?

The trivial case that popped into my mind is that $A=0$ or $B=0$, so the equality holds then, but I wonder what to do in the general case, when both $A\neq0$ and $B\neq0$. Is it even possible to have both of them differ from the null-operator and their composition be a null-operator itself? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but can $A$ and $B$ be represented as matrices?

Comment: For the sake of the argument let's say yes.

Comment: @Element118 Linear transformations between finite dimensional vector spaces can *always* be represented as matrices... Regards

Comment: @Sobanoodles Also for future reference: when choosing titles, make them descriptive and useful. "Proof of an algebraic statement" is unfortunately a very terrible title that could apply to 100k other questions, so it does not do a good job. Regards

Comment: the linked question has my answer, thank you!
@rschwieb I'm aware of that, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Sylvester rank inequality $$r(A)+r(B)-n\leq r(AB)$$